# Celery Beat runs the task every minute

Tags: celery, django-celery, celery-task, celerybeat, celeryd

I am using celery beat for the execution of a task. The configuration is as follows

```
if settings.SETTINGS_MODULE == "irriapp.settings.production":
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'send_alert_season_expired_status_sheduler': {
        'task': 'send_alert_season_expired_status_sheduler',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=12),
    },
}
```

The drawback is that I notice on my monitor in flower that the task is running every minute at 12 am. What is the reason for this?